# FromDate Should be Less Than ToDate in Cakephp Validation

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to compare Effective from date should be less than Effective to date.my demo code is ..

```
 public function addValidations()
        {
            parent::addValidations();
            $this->validate['EffectiveToDate'] = array
            (
                'notempty' => array
                (
                    'rule'    => array('comparison', 'greater or equal', 'EffectiveFromDate'),
                    'allowEmpty' => false,
                    'message' => 'Effective From Date Greater Than To Date.',
                ),
            );
        }
```

so ,please suggest me appropriate solution.

Comment: Question is not clear... Update your question with other relative informations...

Comment: I want date comparision From Date Should be less than to date..

Answer (score 2):

try this code and see if it helps you.

```
public $validate = array(
    'datecompare' => array(
        'rule'    => 'dateCompare',
        'message' => 'Effective From Date Greater Than To Date.'
    )
);

public function dateCompare($check) {
    $datetocheck = strtotime('16/03/2014');
    $today  = strtotime(date('dd/mm/yyyy'));
    if($datetocheck >= $today)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: hello sir, i this case fromdate and todate get into this datecompare function.. i want direct function.

Comment: hello, you can just edit the $today to meet your requirement, example

you can replace it with $this->data['todate']; or what ever is in your form or variable. cheers!

Comment: How to pass dynamic date into this compare function??

Comment: Warning (2): preg_match(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash [APP\Lib\Model\Validator\CakeValidationRule.php, line 279]

Comment: if your validation comes from a form, which i think it is.

you can just do

    $this->Form->input('todate');

Comment: set the name into 'todate'

Comment: I want to get FromDate And Todate post Values into this Compare function??

Comment: public function dateCompare($fromdate, $todate) {
    $datetocheck = $fromdate
    $today  = $todate;
    if($fromdate>= $todate);
    {
        return true;
    }
}

Comment: @Abhishek All the field will be available to you by `$this->request->data('fieldname');`

Comment: In Model $this->request->data('fieldname'); not work

Comment: you dont have to declare the 2nd parameter in model function i think, you can access all field data using $this->request->data('use the field name you want to get the value');